# Is there a way to use a memoryview with regexes in Python 2?

Tags: python

In Python 3, the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module can be used with a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview):

```
~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 20 2013, 14:44:27)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = b"abc"
>>> import re
>>> re.search(b"b", memoryview(x))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f14b5fb8988>
```

However, in Python 2, this does not seem to be the case:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = "abc"
>>> import re
>>> re.search(b"b", memoryview(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I can cast the string to a `buffer`, but looking at the [buffer documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=buffer#buffer), it doesn't mention exactly how a `buffer` works compared to a `memoryview`.

Doing an empirical comparison shows that using a `buffer` object in Python 2 does not offer the performance benefits of using a `memoryview` in Python 3:

```
playground$ cat speed-test.py
import timeit
import sys

print(timeit.timeit("regex.search(mv[10:])", setup='''
import re
regex = re.compile(b"ABC")
PYTHON_3 = sys.version_info >= (3, )
if PYTHON_3:
    mv = memoryview(b"Can you count to three or sing 'ABC?'" * 1024)
else:
    mv = buffer(b"Can you count to three or sing 'ABC?'" * 1024)
'''))
playground$ python2.7 speed-test.py
2.33041596413
playground$ python2.7 speed-test.py
2.3322429657
playground$ python3.2 speed-test.py
0.381270170211792
playground$ python3.2 speed-test.py
0.3775448799133301
playground$
```

If the `regex.search` argument is changed from `mv[10:]` to `mv`, Python 2's performance is roughly the same as Python 3's, but in the code I'm writing, there's lots of repeated string slicing.

Is there a way to circumvent this issue in Python 2 while still having the zero-copy performance benefits of a `memoryview`?

Comment: `Memoryview` [supports the buffer protocol in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview-type). I think the fundamental difference is how `re` gets the buffer pointer between [Python 2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5056e0855c75d3213c67b934923fb63d983875f5/Modules/_sre.c#L1709-L1715) and [Python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f36b73c02f10ebee365cb95d5704195fafaa0b76/Modules/_sre.c#L1692-L1699). There is a PEP dedicate for this change -- have a look at [PEP 3118](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/).

Comment: But why would you use `memoryview` in `re.search`? I don't think you'd get any performance benefits from it.

`~ » python3 -m timeit 'import re; x = b"abc"; re.search(b"b", memoryview(x))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.25 usec per loop`
`~ » python3 -m timeit 'import re; x = b"abc"; re.search(b"b", x)'      1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 usec per loop`

Comment: @SeyeongJeong , that's not a very good test. You're importing the "re" module every single loop, and on top of that, you're recreating a memoryview object every single invocation. In my use case, I'm repeatedly calling re.search at different offsets of a string. With `a_string[offset:]`, Python creates a new string every time, but with `a_memoryview[offset:]`, Python re-uses the existing buffer despite the end-user requesting a slice.

Comment: @SeyeongJeong , I've updated my post with a speed test that matches my scenario more closely than your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I understand the [buffer object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#buffer) in Python 2, you’re supposed to use it without slicing:

```
>>> s = b"Can you count to three or sing 'ABC?'"
>>> str(buffer(s, 10))
"unt to three or sing 'ABC?'"
```

So instead of slicing the resulting buffer, you use the buffer function directly to perform your slicing which results in a fast access to the substring you are interested in:

```
import timeit
import sys
import re

r = re.compile(b'ABC')
s = b"Can you count to three or sing 'ABC?'" * 1024

PYTHON_3 = sys.version_info >= (3, )
if len(sys.argv) > 1: # standard slicing
    print(timeit.timeit("r.search(s[10:])", setup='from __main__ import r, s'))
elif PYTHON_3: # memoryview in Python 3
    print(timeit.timeit("r.search(s[10:])", setup='from __main__ import r, s; s = memoryview(s)'))
else: # buffer in Python 2
    print(timeit.timeit("r.search(buffer(s, 10))", setup='from __main__ import r, s'))
```

I got very similar results in Python 2 and 3 which suggests that using `buffer` like that with the `re` module has a similar effect as the newer `memoryview` (which then seems to be a lazily evaluated buffer):

```
$ python2 .\speed-test.py
0.681979371561
$ python3 .\speed-test.py
0.5693422508853488
```

And as a comparison with standard string slicing:

```
$ python2 .\speed-test.py standard-slicing
7.92006735956
$ python3 .\speed-test.py standard-slicing
7.817641705304309
```

---

If you want to support the slice access (so that you can use the same syntax everywhere), you could easily create a type that dynamically creates a new buffer when you slice on it:

```
class slicingbuffer:
    def __init__ (self, source):
        self.source = source
    def __getitem__ (self, index):
        if not isinstance(index, slice):
            return buffer(self.source, index, 1)
        elif index.stop is None:
            return buffer(self.source, index.start)
        else:
            end = max(index.stop - index.start, 0)
            return buffer(self.source, index.start, end)
```

If you only use it with the `re` module, it could probably work as a direct drop-in replacement for `memoryview`. However, my tests show that this already gives you a large overhead. So you might want to do the opposite instead and wrap Python 3’s memoryview object in a wrapper that gives you the same interface as `buffer`:

```
def memoryviewbuffer (source, start, end = -1):
    return source[start:end]

PYTHON_3 = sys.version_info >= (3, )
if PYTHON_3:
    b = memoryviewbuffer
    s = memoryview(s)
else:
    b = buffer

print(timeit.timeit("r.search(b(s, 10))", setup='from __main__ import r, s, b'))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks to the clarification on how to use buffer, my code is Performant in both Python 2 and 3. I originally had:
`if self._memoryview:
    target = self._memoryview
else:
    target = self.source_code

return target[self.offset:]` but now have `if self._memoryview:
    return self._memoryview[self.offset:]
else:
    return buffer(self.source_code, self.offset)`.

Comment: @ikaros45 memoryview exists and works in the same way, but the `re` module does not work with a memoryview object.